# Firebase - Error Handling Scope

Tags: javascript, firebase, scope, firebase-authentication

Hey I was wondering if someone can take a look at this code and tell me why its not doing what I want it to do.

IF you look within the catch function where the error handling happens I want it to route the page to a certain place, the conditional in the error handling seems to be working.

Ive tested it and if i submit credentials that don't exist in the database it throws the alert i programmed it to throw. Also if the user does exist and the password is wrong it throws that second alert. However if the email is correct and the password is correct - i am assuming it signs in but it doesn't initiate the while loops to route the page.

I am assuming this could either be that maybe since this area is for handling errors and no error occurred I can't use it to route like that. or the scope of this catch function is such that I can't assign the window location from within that area? I would like to know what I have done wrong and if there is another way to do it - i cant just place the loops outside because it will run simultenously and then even if there is an error it will still route the pages which i dont want to happen.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitform() {
      var email_input = document.getElementById("myForm").elements.namedItem("email").value;
      var password_input = document.getElementById("myForm").elements.namedItem("password").value;
      var adminID = document.getElementById("myForm").elements.namedItem("uniqueID").value;  

      if ((email_input.indexOf('.edu') >= 0) && (password_input.length > 4)) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email_input, password_input).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;

          var email_input = document.getElementById("myForm").elements.namedItem("email").value;
          var password_input = document.getElementById("myForm").elements.namedItem("password").value;
          var adminID = document.getElementById("myForm").elements.namedItem("uniqueID").value;

          var schools = ["@fordham.edu", "@sjsu.edu"];
          var mapLocations = ["#select-a-machine", "#select-a-machine"];
          var adminIdLocation = ["#select-a-machine"]
          var adminIDs = ["GJGBING"]        
          var i = 0;
          var a = 0;                            

          if(errorCode === "auth/user-not-found") {
              alert("User does not exist - go ahead and sign up first");
              return;
          } else if(errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") {
              alert("You might have the wrong password, try again");
              return;
          } else {
              while (a < adminIDs.length) {
                  if (adminID.indexOf(adminIDs[a]) >= 0) {
                      window.location.assign(adminIdLocation[a]);
                      break;
                  } else if (adminID.indexOf(adminIDs[a]) < 0) {
                      a++;
                  }
              };

              while (i < schools.length) {
                  if(email_input.indexOf(schools[i]) >= 0) {
                      window.location.assign(mapLocations[i]);
                      break;
                  } else if(email_input.indexOf(schools[i]) < 0) {
                      i++;
                  }
              };

              if(i >= schools.length && (email_input.indexOf('.edu') >= 0)) {
                  alert("We are currently not at your school");
              };
          }         
          // ...
        });                
      } else if ((adminID.indexOf('GJGBING') >= 0) && (password_input.length > 4)) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email_input, password_input).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;

          var email_input = document.getElementById("myForm").elements.namedItem("email").value;
          var password_input = document.getElementById("myForm").elements.namedItem("password").value;
          var adminID = document.getElementById("myForm").elements.namedItem("uniqueID").value;

          var schools = ["@fordham.edu", "@sjsu.edu"];
          var mapLocations = ["#select-a-machine", "#select-a-machine"];
          var adminIdLocation = ["#select-a-machine"]
          var adminIDs = ["GJGBING"]        
          var i = 0;
          var a = 0;                            

          if(errorCode === "auth/user-not-found") {
              alert("User does not exist - go ahead and sign up first");
              return;
          } else if(errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") {
              alert("You might have the wrong password, try again");
              return;
          } else {
              while (a < adminIDs.length) {
                  if (adminID.indexOf(adminIDs[a]) >= 0) {
                      window.location.assign(adminIdLocation[a]);
                      break;
                  } else if (adminID.indexOf(adminIDs[a]) < 0) {
                      a++;
                  }
              };

              while (i < schools.length) {
                  if(email_input.indexOf(schools[i]) >= 0) {
                      window.location.assign(mapLocations[i]);
                      break;
                  } else if(email_input.indexOf(schools[i]) < 0) {
                      i++;
                  }
              };

              if(i >= schools.length && (email_input.indexOf('.edu') >= 0)) {
                  alert("We are currently not at your school");
              };
          }                      
          // ...
        });                 
      } else {
        alert("Please use a .edu email address or enter your unique Admin ID");
        return;
      };  


    };                       
  </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: just based on what i see in the console and the log - nothing seems to come up regarding this part of the code.

Comment: Set up some breakpoints and go through the code while it's running. It should tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I took a quick look and i don't see the .then(function(user) {}) part of your logic. If the login is successful, the catch part will not trigger. You have to move the successful sign in logic there.